# Colombo to Bahamas, transiting through Russia and Cuba, route details - passport only

Tags: transit, international-travel, transit-visas, svo, hav

I'm trying to find a "passport" only route from Sri Lanka to Bahamas (Nassau). I will be planning to spend about 3 months in the Bahamas. We are Sri Lankan nationality, have normal passport, will have return tickets (reverse route), negative COVID test within 72 hours.

I found the following route:

```
04/03: CMB (09:45) to SVO (16:15, Terminal C)   
04/04: SVO (07:25, Terminal D) to HAV (12:30)
04/05: HAV (13:40) to NAS (15:10)
```

I looked at the travel requirements using the emirates tool. The only issue I can see is the "past 12am" layover at SVO and overnight layover at HAV. I don't know if these transit areas are open 24 hours and if so, whether we can grab something to eat or if they have lounge chairs for rest.

Can someone advice if this route is possible?

Edit:
I should mention that CMB to HAV portion will be a single booking. HAV to NAS would be a separate ticket. At least that's what I'm envisioning from flightconnections.com

Comment: I'm not sure that such a route exists today, especially with so many routes no longer flying due to COVID-19. If at all possible, go get a transit visa from the USA (it is easier to get than a tourist visa) and fly through the USA.

Comment: It shows it is available on flightconnections.com and I also verified it is available on aeroflot and bahamas air. The routes start in March however. The thing about US transit visa is that one of the passengers is 31 years old female, unemployed (financially supported by fiance), they don't really have any assets that tie them back to their country so I don't think US would ever give transit visa.

Comment: If you have to get separate tickets then you'll have to clear immigration at that airport. It's easy enough to get the tourist visa from the Cuban embassy in Colombo so that should be no problem for you.

Comment: I wouldn’t count on an comfortable layover in Havana airport https://www.airportsdata.net/airport-HAV-accommodation/ Be prepared for very limited food options and a night on uncomfortable chairs/the floor. The Covid situation in Cuba may have improved by your intended travel date but right now it’s worse than it was at the start; Havana is back in phase1 level restrictions and flights from 6 countries including the Bahamas have been cut https://www.reuters.com/article/us-health-coronavirus-cuba/cuba-tightens-covid-19-measures-as-visitors-fuel-record-contagion-idUSKBN29E0RL?edition-redirect=uk

Comment: It seems Cuba has only banned inbound flights? Outbound (Cuba to Bahamas) is still working? Also, it seems they are not banning out right, they just want a negative COVID test.

Comment: @zwdev2 Yes, Cuba has reduced the *frequency* of flights, not banned outright. As of this Friday, **air operations** with the United States, Mexico, Panama, the Dominican Republic, Haiti and the Bahamas, the countries from which the most travellers carrying the virus have arrived, were **reduced to a minimum**. You’d need to ensure your ‘within 72 hours’ Covid test is valid for all legs of the trip.

Comment: FYI, you can also get a covid test at SVO airport at the health centers of terminals B, D and E, with an additional testing facility in terminal E.

Comment: Do you know if it's a RT-PCR test?